# Code Igniter logging too much

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CI config file I have this logging treshold set:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

In index.php, I have set the following error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

My expectation is that this will log any CI errors that I log (using `log_message('error','my error message')`), as well as any PHP errors. However, I would expect that it will not log PHP notices, only errors. However, when I look at the log files, it seems to log PHP notices too:

> **ERROR - 2009-12-18 13:21:50—> Severity: Notice —> Undefined variable: pageindex /var/www/apps/OS4W/system/application/views/user/view.php 12
>
>   ERROR - 2009-12-18 13:21:50—> Severity: Notice —> Undefined variable: friendsmode /var/www/apps/OS4W/system/application/views/user/activitytable.php 207**

Although the log lines start with “ERROR”, in reality this seems to be a PHP notice, kind of like a warning, that I do not want to log. How can I make sure only CI and PHP errors are logged, yet not PHP notices? I thought `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` would do just that?

Comment: By the way, please ignore the extra underscores in the error reporting function, it is due an issue in StackOverflow's preview panel.

Comment: I edited your formatting to use code blocks rather than blockquotes for the code. Feel free to rollback if you want, but I think it makes more sense to use the code blocks and the correct text.

Comment: Thanks eyelidlessness, definitely an improvement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for thinking along. After considering your advise, I decided to patch the core of CI. Unfortunately, the core classes can be extended, but not the core itself. Therefore if you apply the same patch, be sure to document it.

Here goes. In system\application\config\config.php I added the following custom config setting right below the log_treshold setting:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Exclusions (custom config addition by Ferdy Christant)
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, CI will log all PHP errors, whether it is a notice, warning
| or error. Or, by setting the above treshold to 0, it will log nothing
| In most cases, however, you will want to log PHP errors but not the notices
| In the array below, simply place the PHP error constant that you do NOT
| want to see logged. 
|
| For a live site you'll usually use the config as follow:
|
| $config['exclude_logging'] = array(E_STRICT,E_NOTICE);
|
*/

$config['exclude_logging'] = array(E_STRICT,E_NOTICE);
```

As the documentation explains, in this config array you put the PHP error types that you do **NOT** want to log.

Next, I have patched the core file (system/codeigniter/Common.php) and edited the function _exception_handler

There are two changes. First, I moved the config loading line to the top of the method, since I need it earlier.  Find the line below and you will see $config =& get_config(); under it. Delete that.

I removed the     // Should we log the error?  No?  We're done...

Second, the check for severity is modified to check for the array that we declared. Go to the top of the method and replace the if statement that checks $severity == E_STRICT with below:

```
$config =& get_config();
if (in_array($severity,$config['exclude_logging']))
{
return;
}
```

These patches allow for fine-grained control over PHP error logging. Normal CI logging will of course still work. As mentioned, the only downside is that this patches the core.

I hope this helps anyone. Thank you for thinking along!

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else that might come across this with CodeIgniter 2.0.  The problem is still the same, but the solution is "easier".

You still have to modify a core file: `/system/codeigniter/Common.php`

Find the `_exception_handler()` function (should be at the bottom), and change this line:

`if ($severity == E_STRICT)` **to this:** `if ($severity == E_STRICT OR $severity == E_NOTICE)`

Funny how they think `E_STRICT` *notices* will fill up the log; but `E_NOTICE` won't. Or maybe it's good to punish people for not coding strictly and declaring all their variables before using them? :)

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying all the other stuff for 2.x and none of it worked.  This did.

Answer (score 3):

According to the PHP error reporting docs at https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

> In PHP 4 and PHP 5 the default value
> is E_ALL  & ~E_NOTICE. This setting
> does not show E_NOTICE level errors.
> You may want to show them during
> development.

I'd try changing your error_reporting() to "E_ALL  & ~E_NOTICE" and see if that works.

Dana

Edit: Well, I spoke too soon. I tried this and it stopped the notice from showing up on screen, but still logged it to the log file.

Solution:

OK I think I figured this out. In the common.php file there's a function called "_exception_handler" that handles the logging process. It does some bitwise comparisons of the current severity level and the error_reporting level to see if it should log to the screen, but it does not do so for logging to the log file. IT just passes everything through except for E_STRICT messages which it tosses regardless.

What you can do is wrap the very last line in this function with the same IF statement they use for logging to the screen. So the entire function becomes:

```
function _exception_handler($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{   
 // We don't bother with "strict" notices since they will fill up
 // the log file with information that isn't normally very
 // helpful.  For example, if you are running PHP 5 and you
 // use version 4 style class functions (without prefixes
 // like "public", "private", etc.) you'll get notices telling
 // you that these have been deprecated.

if ($severity == E_STRICT)
{
    return;
}

$error =& load_class('Exceptions');

// Should we display the error?
// We'll get the current error_reporting level and add its bits
// with the severity bits to find out.  
if (($severity & error_reporting()) == $severity)
{
    $error->show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
}

// Should we log the error?  No?  We're done...
$config =& get_config();
if ($config['log_threshold'] == 0)
{
    return;
}

if (($severity & error_reporting()) == $severity)
{
    $error->log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
}
}
```

and I think that will take care of it. Then you can use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

in your index.php. Of course we're editing the core here. Maybe there's a way to override instead?

Dana

Comment: For normal PHP, I think this is correct, but I think Code Igniter sees all PHP errors (whether a notice or actual error) as the same and will log all or nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing with it this morning. Tried changing it at the server level but CI ignores those. Can't see any way around it except maybe digging into CI core.

Comment: Thank you so much for investigating, I appreciate it. I applied your patch to the core, yet found that when using error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE) it will display notices on screen, strangely as that sounds. I've read on the CI forum that there are logging plugins, so I think I'm going to investigate that path. If I succeed, I'll report back here so that all can benefit.

Comment: I did not experience the logging to screen when using E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE. Odd. Yeah, I'd be interested in seeing what you find.

Answer (score 2):

try this, no need to patch CI core:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'class'    => 'MY_Commonfunction_hook',
    'function' => 'hook',
    'filename' => 'MY_Commonfunction_hook.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks');

class MY_Commonfunction_hook {
    public function hook() {
        set_error_handler('_my_exception_handler');
    }
}

function _my_exception_handler($severity, $message, $filepath, $line) {
    if ($severity == E_STRICT) {
        return;
    }
    $_error = & load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
    if (($severity & error_reporting()) == $severity) {
        for ($i = ob_get_level(); $i > 0; $i--) {
            @ob_end_clean();
        }
        $_error->show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
    }
    if (config_item('log_threshold') == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (($severity & error_reporting()) == $severity) {
        $_error->log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need just one underscore in the error_reporting method call that PHP doesn't report those notices:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

Code Igniter will treat any error from PHP (whether it's a notice, warning, or fatal error, etc.) as an error in your CI logs.

Edit: Nevermind, just saw your comment. Not sure what's going on with your error reporting.

Comment: Your answer still is interesting, specifically where you say "Code Igniter will treat any error from PHP (whether it's a notice, warning, or fatal error, etc.) as an error in your CI logs.". 

Am I crazy or is this highly undesired behavior of CI? This kind of make it an all or nothing deal: Either log a ton or log nothing at all, not even an error. Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that CI this way severely handicaps PHP's error reporting.

Comment: This is set with a config option, everything or nothing is incorrect. Where did you hear this?

Comment: I did not "hear" this, I know it. I have tested and debugged it and that is how CI works. The config option you talk about controls CI errors, not PHP errors. It will either log all PHP errors or none at all. CI errors you can control using that config setting.

Answer (score 1):

I've always just modified that logging library of CodeIgniter. Ferdy is correct when he says CI will log either everything or nothing. It's very undesired.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by changing ids for log levels in libraries/Log.php6 like:

change:

```
protected $_levels  = array('ERROR' => '1', 'DEBUG' => '2',  'INFO' => '3', 'ALL' => '4');
```

to:

```
protected $_levels  = array('ERROR' => '1', 'DEBUG' => '3',  'INFO' => '2', 'ALL' => '4');
```